# Is it possible to rebuild pg_depend?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgres-bdr

I have a PostgreSQL 9.4 database affected by the following bug in [BDR](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/postgres-bdr-2ndquadrant/):

https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/bdr/issues/309

In a nutshell, that bug in BDR resulted in missing dependencies in the [`pg_depend` system catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/catalog-pg-depend.html).  Now when I use `pg_dump`, objects are dumped out of order and the dump can't be used without manual editing.

Is there a way to make PostgreSQL rebuild the dependencies in `pg_depend` without rebuilding the database from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because that information is not redundant (that would be a problem).

Manually messing with `pg_depend` is likely to make things worse.

Your best bet is to create a schema-only dump (`pg_dump --section=pre-data`) and massage that manually until you can load it into a new database (some dependencies will still be lost, e.g. columns owning a sequence).

Once you have succeeded with that, use `ALTER` statements to adjust further dependencies you notice are missing.

Once you are happy with the result, dump the rest of the database (`pg_dump --section=data` and `pg_dump --section=post-data`) and restore them into the database in this order.

I'm afraid you cannot do better than that.

Comment: I ended up using a variation of your technique, namely the `-l` and `-L` command line options to `pg_restore`, with manual edits to the listing file to get things in the right order.